# Getting Firebase Bearer token by simple HttpCall (REST API)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I am currently facing the following situation.

Sending Firebase Messages via HttpCall via the google API endpoint:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/messages:send
Here we have to use OAuth2.0 with a valid Bearer Token like discussed in this question:

What Bearer token should I be using for Firebase Cloud Messaging testing?

After following these steps I was able to send Firebase Messages via the google API.

Now I would like to get the Bearer Token via a HttpCall without doing the manual step with the Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.

I cannot find any documentation on how to "Exchange authorization code for tokens" via simple HttpCall. I have no possibility to implement any code because I would like to send Firebase messages inside a "Dataverse Cloud Flow/PowerAutomate", therefore no possibility to load any external DLL (like the Firebase Admin Dll, which would implement this functionality).

I am not,looking for a solution which depends on external Dll like https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_access_token or Pre-RequestScript

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you open to making use of a [HTTP Event Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that accepts some form of basic authentication (email-pass, private key) to proxy the request to the Firebase Messaging API? This would allow you to use cURL to make a HTTP request to an endpoint like `https://us-central1-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/ci/messaging/messages:send` using a private API key.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is fundamentally not possible, since you can't hook the result of the bearer token into the same URL process to send messages. By the sounds of it you are unable to fetch one URL, process the results from that URL to pass onto the other which is what the REST API would do.

As such, you will need a secondary service that you can simply send messages to and it will invoke the Message and authentication for you, a bridge as you will. You can use Firebase Cloud Functions with an `onRequest` call or a simple express server on a Google Compute Engine instance (f1 free tier).

Then you can send your message request from your service to this bridge which will authenticate for you and send the message, it would be a fairly simple script to implement, specially with the admin-sdk.