# What should be the scope that can be mentioned to generate code to get refresh token for fcm push notification?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to firebase push notification.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

When I type above url in browser I get a code to to be used in following client side post call

```
{
    grant_type=authorization_code,
    redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth2.0:oob,
    code=code get from browser
    client_id=your_client_id,
    client_secret=your_client_secret,
}
```

But scope=https://gdata.youtube.com in above url should be replaced with firebase push notification url. Then only I can do above call. So I would like to know what should be the scope for firebase push notification? I mean what is replacement of https://gdata.youtube.com in above url. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the answer from [What Bearer token should I be using for Firebase Cloud Messaging testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399170/what-bearer-token-should-i-be-using-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-testing) link. It is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging