# SenderId mismatch, PERMISSION_DENIED Firebase FCM v1

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification using FCM, but it gives an error,
I have created a fresh project in Firebase.

**how can I generate a new server key? as mentioned in the below image?**

*Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA*

my PHP code

```
<?php
$serverKey = 'ya29.a0AfB_byDuIRA2ZCRIgemWrXw0utBdCHfdlNJAwVGve5NNgeTPp9X_KMuvGS7v9AgjAY4wWLL2MHjxdmpznGJ2ZC9Y6PJMP6472RQ82g0GtS_xjZKDlrJKJYgeTw-2KwNcTgTMEUL-W9Tq1uXypuscSQX6jUsDMgo-RRHuaCgYKASASARISFQHGX2Mij39fW1eEtCcxC3aouQsyyw0171';

$deviceToken = 'MY VALID DEVICE TOKEN';

$messageData = [
    'message' => [
        'token' => $deviceToken,
        'notification' => [
            'title' => 'Title of the Notification',
            'body' => 'Body of the Notification',
        ],
    ],
];

$jsonData = json_encode($messageData);

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $serverKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/push-notification-g28f2/messages:send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$decodedResponse = json_decode($result, true);

echo 'Response: <pre>' . json_encode($decodedResponse, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>';

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "SenderId mismatch",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

please help me with this, I'm stuck very badly, and I don't know how to fix it.
I have referred to the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399170/what-bearer-token-should-i-be-using-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-testing), but still facinf same error.

**After too much R&D on Google, I found that my *$serverKey*', was wrong generated,
like the below image, so someone please help with this?
how can I generate a new server key? as mentioned in the below image?**

*Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA*

I have tried adding the server key using Postman, I have downloaded the JSON file from Google Console and added data one by one, like below

In Postman open "Authorization" tab, select Type = "OAuth 2.0" than click "Get New Access Token". Dialog appears.

Fields:
Token Name - type what you want

Grant Type = Authorization Code

Callback URL = redirect_uris from downloaded json

Auth URL = auth_uri

Access Token URL = token_uri

Client ID = client_id

Client Secret = client_secret

Scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"

State - leave empty

Client Authentication = default, Send As Basic Auth Header

Click "Request Token"

and fetch new server key

still i get same error

Postman Images

[authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md0rG.png)

[new server key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmKzq.png)
[serverky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHlfs.png)

Comment: Permission denied means that the token you provided is incorrect. Also please review the [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Then Edit your question.

Comment: @AdamBasha which token? Android token?

Comment: @AdamBasha i have created Bearer token from google oauthplayground.