# Google Firestore - REST Read/Write via Postman

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore, postman

This is the view of my database, very simple:
[image]

These are my Firestore rules (default):

[image]

And this is the response of the server when I try to do a GET of collection 'colA':

[image]

What can be wrong?

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: It seems like there's a problem with the auth parameter since error states that the field could not be found in request message. I would recommend checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661839/using-postman-to-access-firebase-rest-api) that might help you build the correct request to firestore using Postman. I hope it helps.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the prior revisions.

Comment: @Christopher Rodriguez Conde thanks, but my question is about the Cloud Firestore database and not about the Firebase Real-time database. They seem to work different.

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls) you will find information on how to do make rest calls to the Firestore API. Furthermore, since it's seems a problem with one of your arguments, I also recommend you to check the [Cloud Firestore API](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/?apix=true), but it's seems like the `auth` argument is not valid. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/get) you could also try the method you are trying to use. I hope it helps.